# Stripe Redirect URI - Dynamic number in url

Tags: stripe-payments, stripe-connect

I want to set UserId in redirect URI of Stripe, My URL changes like this

```
www.mydomain.com/registration/1
www.mydomain.com/registration/2
```

I have `www.mydomain.com/registration/` set in redirect URI which works fine but breaks when Stripe sees that number in URI

I need to: Connect the users to Stripe using [this](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/standalone-accounts#connecting-users) feature

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should just redirect to one page on your site.

That one page can either:
a) finalize the oauth process and then do the redirect, or 
b) redirect to the page that will complete the oauth process

Comment: This sounds promising but I am expecting some solution at Stripe Redirect URI.

Comment: This would be the only solution, the redirect URI is not dynamic, though you can use a state query string parameter which Stripe will append to your redirect uri.

Comment: The state query string can have information embedded in it.

Comment: do URLs being sent in query string require to be registered in Stripe connect settings? I wanna achieve this feature without registering it before, but on runtime when I send query string.

Answer (score 0):

You can literally use a url in your app like this:

```
<a 
  href={`https://dashboard.stripe.com/oauth/authorize?response_type=code&state=${profile?.id}&client_id=${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_STRIPE_OAUTH_CLIENT_ID}&scope=read_write&redirect_uri=localhost.com/business/verify`}
>  Connect with Stripe </a>
```